# Implementing Singleton pattern with IIFE in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Employees that previously worked at my company used the following form of the Singleton pattern to create and obtain UI components in JavaScript:

```
getDetailForm: function() {
    this.getDetailForm = (function() {
        var form = // form creation logic

        return function() {
            return form;
        };
    }());

    return this.getDetailForm();
}
```

Is there any reason to use that variation over the following standard way?

```
getDetailForm: function() {
    var form;

    if (!form) {
        form = // form creation logic
    }

    return form;
}
```

Comment: Well, in your second example, `if (!form) {` will always be `true`. Both examples do different things. The first only creates the `form` once, the second creates it every time `getDetailForm` is called. Which one to choose depends on what you want.

Comment: @FelixKling No, if form is not initialized (!form) would be true, but when initialized (and it happens inside the if) !form would be false, (except if form is a "false-castable" value like 0, in that case !0 is equal to !false and then would be true.)

Comment: Please read about closures, @Sycraw.

Comment: @Sycraw: With every call to `getDetailForm`, a new *empty* `form` variable is created. Therefore `!form` will be `true` every time the function is called. The `form` variable does *not* persist between function calls. Note that I'm only talking about the second example.

Comment: I've understood and I know about closures, you've right I misunderstood the code above, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The second code block will not remember the value of the variable *form*: every time the function *getDetailForm* is called, it represents a new closure, and a new variable *form* is created within that scope, which will start out as `undefined` -- each time.

See how the following prints *"init"* on each call:

```js
var o = {
    getDetailForm: function() {
        var form;
        if (!form) {
            form = 'form'; // form creation logic
            console.log('init');
        }
        return form;
    }
}

console.log(o.getDetailForm());
console.log(o.getDetailForm());
```

You can make it work by declaring *form* in the scope of your singleton object, and for that you could use a constructor for instantiating that object, which at the same time is a closure for your *form* variable:

```js
var o = new function () {
    var form;
    this.getDetailForm = function() {
        if (!form) {
            form = 'form'; // form creation logic
            console.log('init');
        }
        return form;
    }
};

console.log(o.getDetailForm());
console.log(o.getDetailForm());
```

See how the output now only shows *"init"* once.

#### The difference

The first version you provided has a tiny advantage: after the first call the function will have been replaced by a very basic function:

```
function() {
    return form;
};
```

There is not even an `if` in that function. It is only a `return`. One could argue that therefore it is to be preferred: no performance is lost by the evaluation of an `if` condition on any subsequent calls of this function, which, when you call the method many times, always returns the same result, except for the first time.

However, also that can be achieved with the constructor pattern, if you would assign the value to *form* directly in the constructor function. Then you don't need the `if` in the method any more, as the initialisation already took place in the constructor.

Note that this is not exactly the same, because now the constructor is doing the heavy lifting of assigning the (maybe very time consuming) expression to *form*. The advantage of the first code you provided, is that this is only done when the function is called the first time, which you could consider an advantage: "don't waste time on things that might never be used".

Comment: You're right.  I actually meant to use "this.form" instead of "var form" so that the same form will be returned for each call.

I like it because it's simple.  The pattern my former colleagues used was more complicated, so I was wondering if it has any advantages over the pattern of checking if the component has already been created and creating it if it hasn't?

Comment: I added some considerations about this to my answer. Note that with the code you mention here, you add a visible property to your object (`this.form`), which might be a side-effect you don't want: the user of that object could change the value of `form` just like that.